# looping code: infinite how to stop this

Tags: python, loops, infinite

Hi I was trying to create a loop so that when someone dies in my code  it would stop and     likewise    the code wouldn't end until someone died (that is, there strentgth or skill reached zero) however, no matter what numbers I put in, the game always continues infinitely.

How do I solve this?

```
while True:
    try:
        strengthA=abs(int(input("enter strength A ")))
        break          
    except ValueError:
        print("Error")
        print ("value entered")
while True:
    try:

        strengthB=abs(int(input("enter strength B ")))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error")
        print ("value entered successfully")

while True:
    try:
        skillA=abs(int(input("enter skillA ")))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error")
        print ("value entered successfully ")

while True:
    try:
        skillB=abs(int(input("enter skill B ")))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error")
        print ("value entered successfully")



strengthmod=abs(int((strengthA-strengthB)/5))
print (strengthmod)
skillmod=abs(int((skillA-skillB)/5))
print(skillmod)


while strengthA>0 and strengthB>0:
    print strengthA, strengthB
    import random
    throwA=int(random.randrange(6)+1)
    print("Cloudy throws "+str(throwA))
    throwB=int(random.randrange(6)+1)
    print("Mocha throws "+str(throwB))

    if throwA>throwB:

        print("Cloudy wins!")
        skillA=skillA+skillmod
        strengthA=strengthA+strengthmod
        skillB=skillB-skillmod
        strengthB=strengthB-strengthmod
    elif throwA<throwB:
        print("Mocha wins!")
        skillA=skillA-skillmod
        strengthA=strengthA-strengthmod
        skillB=skillB+skillmod
        strengthB=strengthB+strengthmod
    else:
        print ("No one wins")


    if skillA<1:
        skillA=0
    if skillB<1:
        skillB=0
    print("Cloudy new skill " +str(skillA))
    print("Mocha new skill " +str(skillB))
    print("Cloudy new strength " +str(strengthA))
    print("Mocha new strength " +str(strengthB))
    if strengthA<1:
        print ("Cloudy dies")
    if strengthB<1:
        print ("Mocha dies")
    print ("Battle ends")
```

Comment: It's impossible to read what's going on without indentation. Could you please fix it, or upload your code to https://gist.github.com/ ?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this, is by setting a variable which changes on the critical condition (somebody dies). Then replace the upper while loop to check for the state of this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `strengthA` and `strengthB` are to close to each other, `strengthmod` will be `0`:

```
strengthmod=abs(int((strengthA-strengthB)/5))
```

So `strengthA` and `strengthB` will never change:

```
...
strengthB=strengthB-strengthmod
...
strengthA=strengthA-strengthmod
...
```

so the `while` loop

```
while strengthA>0 and strengthB>0:
```

runs forever.

Maybe you should make sure that `strengthA` and `strengthB` will change, even if `strengthmod` is `0`, e.g.:

```
strengthB=strengthB-max(strengthmod, 1)
```